# Using raspberry Pi o run a single application

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

I Am currently working on a project, and my idea is to build an application in C#, that runs on the Raspberry pi 2 with windows 10 IoT. My requirements are that the application starts automatically when the device is powered on, and is the only application that a user can interact with. (I cannot remember the technical term, but its similar to how an ATM runs on XP, but the user never sees XP, only the application to carry out transactions. I would like to use the Pi in this way.)

Is this possible?? If so, how would I go about achieving my goal?

Any help is Appreciated

Comment: AFAIK Win 10 IOT core runs headless on Raspberry Pi.. If you want a UI based application then You should go for other options.

Comment: Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're building a windows universal application, it should satisfy your needs by setting your app as the default app.

Go to Web-based device management portal, select Apps tab, choose your app in the installed apps list and click Set Default.

Comment: Thanks. I never realised it was that simple.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for running apps with win10: headed and headless.  Headless runs in the background and is suitable for computations or tasks that require no user interaction.  In your case, where you want the user to do something, you want a headed app.

take a look at Microsoft's IOT site and there are lots of samples describing how to get started: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/iot

Comment: can you share any link which have information about running win10 headed?

Comment: @yamspog this doesn't mention how to make it "the only application that a user can interact with"